# matplotlib,savefig,How to save a picture beyond the plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a lot of data to draw a scatter. if I change the x limit to show all the scatter diagram,when I save it as file,I can`t see the detail. but if I zoom in,the picture saved is part of the whole scatter diagram.
What can I do to save the zoom in scatter diagram?
Thanks very much!

```
f.savefig('output.png', dpi=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the range of your x or y axis via xlim or ylim.
The documentation (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#xlim) says that these functions

> Get or set the x limits of the current axes.

In your code, you would call

```
plt.xlim(x1, x2)
plt.ylim(y1, y2)
```

before you call `plt.show()`.

Comment: My final destination is to save the Enlarged images,if I use xlim & ylim to show the whole diagram,some text will overlap

Comment: Are you trying to have a zoomed inset plot or what?

Comment: DO you care just about the zoomed part?

Comment: I want get the whole part.In my grogram,I have uesd xlim()&ylim() to make the axes can show all my data in one time.than ,I use savefig() to save it as picture.My problem is in this step,I want to get the zoomed and whole picture

Comment: when I zoom,some part is outside the  region of (xmin,xmax)